# App causes AOT (optimizing apps) on every reboot

Tags: android

My Android app seems to cause Ahead of time compilation after every reboot for some users.
Only the single app is optimized: Optimizing App 1 of 1

The app uses JNI if that matters. I have no idea where to start looking. Ideas?

Comment: To the user who downvoted: why? If I could give more information or code I would...

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is: can you verify that this is not an issue of the users phone? I.e. buy the phone and try.

Comment: `"If I could give more information or code I would"`. Well you can. The manifest would be a good start to give an indication of compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, proguard settings etc...

Comment: You can try adding `<application android:vmSafeMode="true" />` to your manifest xml and disable the AOT compilation

Comment: do you have broadcast receiver of reboot in your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by D8 and will be fixed:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77842465

Comment: Can confirm fixed in Android Studio 3.1.3