# Android "optimizing" my app (libgdx game, actually) on every reboot, still app runs very slow when launched

Tags: android, performance, libgdx, android-studio-3.1

**EDIT: it really was a bug in AS 3.1.1 related to D8 compiler as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361994/app-causes-aot-optimizing-apps-on-every-reboot). It's said to be fixed by now in AS 3.1.3, although I didn't check that myself.**

I know it means it performing AOT compilation.

The thing is that I get a lot of reviews saying "everything was fine before the latest update, but the game is extremely slow now" from users on Android 6.0 and above. Some users report that sometimes the game can not respond to their actions for literally minutes.

Also, a few reviews said that the game is a cause their phones reboot takes a very long time saying it's "optimizing apps 1/1" and that the issue goes away when they uninstall my game from the device.

I cannot reproduce the issues on any devices I have on hand (I have no Android 6.0 unfortunately, only 5.1 phone and 7.1 tablet - the game runs smoothly on those)

I need help to figure out the cause of the problem.

What I did before the latest update (that caused the problem):

- switched from AS 3.0 to 3.1 (and updated project to use a newer version of gradle - 4.4)
- updated android support libraries to 26.0.1
- updated Appodeal libraries to 2.1.11
- updated libgdx version from 1.9.5 to 1.9.6

Also, I made a few minor changes in the game's core code, but I see no way of them causing system-wide issues, it has to be something of the above. Are there any knows issues with these versions of libraries?

Comment: Have you tried posting on the libgdx forums? Might get a bit more help there.

Comment: I've just run into the same problem. I also cannot reproduce the issue on any device including my nexus 7 running 6.0.1. However, a user was able to reproduce on 2 different Android 6 devices and helped me narrow down the bug to a gradle update from version 4.1 to 4.4. Gradle 4.4 adds the new DEX compiler (d8) so I suspect that is related. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin. It would be interested to see if downgrading gradle solved this for you. In the link you can also disable d8 with android.enableD8=false in gradle.properties which I haven't tried yet but may work.

Comment: Yes I turned enableD8 to false, but I also reverted ads libs I was using to older versions and didn't know which of those really solved the issue. Had no time to check it back then, but I'm inclined to think it is D8's fault.

Comment: It would be great if you could try it and confirm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App causes AOT (optimizing apps) on every reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361994/app-causes-aot-optimizing-apps-on-every-reboot)

Comment: @paul thank you, I believe it is, glad we've finally found the real cause :)